# Math word for an object not centered at the origin?

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

Is there a word that can describe a geometric figure such as a circle or ellipse that is not centered at origin (0, 0) in cartesian space? I'd like to find an agreed upon mathematical word, but if it doesn't exist then a substitute "non-mathematical" word would do as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Eccentric**

...2 ... b : located elsewhere than at the geometrical center; also : having the axis or support so located [M-W Online]

The actual 'centre' of whatever is being talked about is subject to context; 'positioned eccentrically' might be preferred to clarify that the Cartesian space is being used as the frame of reference.

Comment: This isn't the way mathematicians use *"eccentric"*. The [*eccentricity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_(mathematics)) of an ellipse measures how much it differs from a circle; not how far away it is from the origin.

Comment: @Peter Yes that's what the eccentricity of an ellipse is, but the word "eccentric* does mean off-centre as required. One would still need to add something referring to the origin though.

Answer (score 0):

Off-center: not quite in the center of something. [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/off-centre?q=off-center).

Comment: As with "eccentric", one would need to say something about the *origin* to give what the OP is looking for. One could refer to a shape "not centred on the origin", "off-centre/eccentric in relation to the origin", and so on. I can't think of a word which does all this on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend phrases like *not origin-centered* or *arbitrarily located* or *in general position* to describe a circle whose center is not at the origin.  In the field of computational geometry, *general position* is a technical term for non-degenerate arrangements or configurations of objects, so using it to mean a circle isn't origin-centered is a minor abuse of terminology.

The Merriam-Webster meaning of *[eccentric](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eccentric)* mentioned in another answer,  “located elsewhere than at the geometrical center”, is relevant primarily to the location of a crank, driver arm, or axle attached to a wheel or gear, rather than to mathematical circles.  That sense of *eccentric* says nothing of where a circle's center is.  Merriam-Webster illustrates the sense with the phrase *an eccentric wheel*.

Note that *eccentricity* has a well-known and well-defined mathematical meaning.  For example, from [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eccentricity):

> The ratio, constant for any particular conic section, of the distance of a point from the focus to its distance from the directrix.
>   [eg] *For an ellipse, the eccentricity is the ratio of the distance from the center to a focus divided by the length of the semi-major axis.*

Because of that well-known mathematical meaning, it's inappropriate to use either of the terms *eccentric* or *eccentricity* to refer to the location of a circle's center.

It's more usual to refer to locations and alignments of foci or axes of an ellipse, rather than to a center.  The *not origin-centered* appellation can be misleading or ambiguous for ellipses, making *arbitrarily located* or *in general position* better choices.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the term "translated"  (http://i.word.com/idictionary/translate def 4)

May not always be appropriate. If something had been translated, it's generally to a specific location or by a specific amount. However, I suppose it could be translated by a random amount.